# Calling xlwings from Excel "No module named..." Error

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I'm trying to learn the ropes of starting a Python script from Excel VBA using xlwings 0.9.2.  According to the docs, I need to change the `PYTHONPATH` to the path for my py file. I've seen several versions of this question, and various answers, but none have addressed my specific scenario. I have a basic test module "module1.py" and an Excel file "Book2.xlsm" located on the desktop which has a button to run this macro:

```
Sub macro1()
RunPython ("import module1.py; module1.run_all()")
End Sub
```

module1 goes like this:

```
import xlwings as xw

def run_all():
    wb.Book.caller()
    xw.sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value = "Done!"
    return
```

I then imported the "xlwings.bas" file and edited the VBA code to read `PYTHONPATH = "C:\Users\bwamp\Desktop\module1\module1`, which refers to the subfolder that holds "module1.py" (full path: "C:\Users\bwamp\Desktop\module1\module1\module1.py", for clarity). Press the button to run `macro1` and I get the following error:

---

### Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

ImportError: No module named 'module1.py'; 'module1' is not a package

### Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.

### OK

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors: You need to import your module without the `.py` ending:

```
Sub macro1()
RunPython ("import module1; module1.run_all()")
End Sub
```

And it's `xw.Book.caller()` instead of `wb.Book.caller()`.

Comment: I knew it was something simple!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Solved by downgrade to xlwings version 0.7.2